# Execute JavaScript when tapping on notification

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, apn

I'm using the Phonegap Pushplugin with Cordova to implement notifications on iOS.

I managed to get as far as registering the device and sending notifications successfully. However when I tap on the notification, I cannot execute a piece of JavaScript to open the relevant page in the application.

```
window.onNotificationAPN = function(event) {
    if ( event.alert )
    {
        navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
        //call JavaScript here?
    }

    if ( event.sound )
    {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
    }

    if ( event.badge )
    {
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
    }
}
```

I tried adding my Javascript under if(event.alert) but it does not get executed. The data that my JavaScript code should be using is sent as part of the notification payload.
What am I doing wrong?